# Drupal | Dynamic Primary link menus

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-navigation

I have a primary link menu and sub menu. I have created it through drupal configurations. But somehow sub menu needs to be dynamic based on contents. I have an array of menu and sub menu with title and path, this array is dynamic with time to time. I want to write a code which will delete the previously available sub menus and add the new sub menu.

So basically question is how can I delete the available primary link sub menu from code and add new sub menu?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use token module, as it will produce a dynamic link(menu) according to your content or node.

[Download here](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token)

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but I am getting the dynamic array from somewhere else through webservice :)